# Calculating $\int_{0}^{\pi}\text{sinh}\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)\text{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I was wondering if it exists a beautiful exact value to
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\text{sinh}\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)\text{d}x$$
which has a nice graph over $\left[0,\pi\right]$, but i can't get to compute it.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any reason to think that a closed form exists?

Comment: WA gives only a numerical result.

Comment: WA is aware of this integral: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%CF%80+(StruveL(0,+1)) (see Integral representations)

Answer (score 4):

If you know the Beta and Gamma functions well, you can see the sequence $$a_n:=\int_0^\pi\sin^{2n+1}x\mathrm{d}x=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n+1}x\mathrm{d}x=\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{1}{2},\,n+1\right)=\frac{n!\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$satisfies$$a_0=2,\,\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2(n+1)}{2n+3}$$so by induction$$a_n=2^{n+1}\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{i}{2i-1}=\frac{2^{2n+1}n!^2}{(2n+1)!}.$$So your integral is $$2\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{n!^2}{(2n+1)!^2}4^n=\pi L_0(1),$$with $L_n(x)$ the [modified Struve function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedStruveFunction.html). (I'm not an expert on this function myself, but [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(n!*2%5En%2F(2n%2B1)!)%5E2+from+0+to+infinity) gives the result, and I suspect it can be derived from the previous link's Eq. (1) using [Legendre's duplication formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html).)

Comment: If I am not mistaken there is a factor $(2n+1)$ missing in the denominator. According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*sum_(n%3D0)%5E(infinity)+4%5En*(n!)%5E2%2F((2n)!*(2n%2B1)!)) your sum equals about $2.7124$ whereas, with the extra factor, the sum [becomes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*sum_(n%3D0)%5E(infinity)+4%5En*(n!)%5E2%2F((2n%2B1)!%5E2)) about $2.23129$ which seems to agree with the [numerical evaluation of the integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Epi+sinh(sin+x)).

Comment: Can you please explain what does $a_n$ have anything to do with the integral?

Comment: @Zacky By writing $\sinh\sin x$ as a power series in $\sin x$.

Comment: Oh got it! I was trying to write $2\sinh(\sin x)$ as $e^{\sin x}-e^{-\sin x}$  then to expand into power series too.

Comment: @mrtaurho Thanks; fixed. The modified Struve function is still useful.

Answer (score 1):

Using the integral representation of the [modified Struve function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedStruveFunction.html) linked by *J.G.* which is given by

> $$\mathbf L_\nu(z)~=~\frac{2\left(\frac12 z\right)^\nu}{\sqrt \pi~\Gamma\left(\nu+\frac12\right)}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sinh(z\cos t)\sin^{2\nu}t~\mathrm dt\tag1$$

By setting $z=1,\nu=0$ and after reflection on $\frac\pi2$ we almost obtain the desired integral. Precisely we got that

\begin{align*}
\mathbf L_0(1)&=\frac{2\left(\frac12 1\right)^0}{\sqrt \pi~\Gamma\left(0+\frac12\right)}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sinh(1\cdot\cos t)\sin^{2\cdot 0}t~\mathrm dt\\
\mathbf L_0(1)&=\frac1{ \pi}2\underbrace{\int_0^{\pi/2}\sinh(\cos t)~\mathrm dt}_{t\mapsto \frac\pi2-t}\\
\mathbf L_0(1)&=\frac1{ \pi}2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sinh(\sin t)~\mathrm dt
\end{align*}

On the other hand the original integral is symmetric towards $x=\frac\pi2$. Thus

$$\int_0^\pi\sinh(\sin t)~\mathrm dt=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sinh(\sin t)~\mathrm dt+\underbrace{\int_{\pi/2}^\pi\sinh(\sin t)~\mathrm dt}_{t\mapsto \pi-t}=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sinh(\sin t)\mathrm dt$$

> $$\therefore~\int_0^\pi\sinh(\sin t)~\mathrm dt~=~2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sinh(\sin t)\mathrm dt~=~\pi\mathbf L_0(1)$$

I guess closer to an actual closed-form we will not get. However, on the other hand the modified Struve function has got a series represenation given by

> $$\mathbf L_\nu(z)~=~\left(\frac12 z\right)^{\nu+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac12 z\right)^{2n}}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac32\right)\Gamma\left(n+\nu+\frac32\right)}\tag2$$

Again setting $z=1$ and $\nu=0$ to get

\begin{align*}
\mathbf L_0(1)&=\left(\frac12 1\right)^{0+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac12 1\right)^{2n}}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac32\right)\Gamma\left(n+0+\frac32\right)}\\
\mathbf L_0(1)&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4^{-n}}{\Gamma^2\left(n+\frac32\right)}\\
\mathbf L_0(1)&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4^{-n}}{\left(n+\frac12\right)^2\Gamma^2\left(n+\frac12\right)}\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac12\right)}{\Gamma^2\left(\frac12\right)}\\
\mathbf L_0(1)&=\frac2\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4^{-n}}{\left(2n+1\right)^2}\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right)}\right)^2\\
\mathbf L_0(1)&=\frac2\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4^{-n}}{\left(2n+1\right)^2}\left(\frac{4^nn!}{(2n)!}\right)^2\\
\mathbf L_0(1)&=\frac2\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4^n (n!)^2}{(2n+1)^2(2n)!^2}
\end{align*}

> $$\therefore~2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4^n (n!)^2}{(2n+1)!^2}~=~\pi\mathbf L_0(1)$$

The latter agrees perfectly wiht *J.G.* sum representation aswell as with the integral representation.

Answer (score 0):

The integrand is not integratable in terms of elementary function but we have the following series representation:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\text{sinh}\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)\text{d}x=2\cdot\sum_{k=0}^\infty \Bigg(\frac{2^k \cdot k!}{(2k+1)!}\Bigg)^2$$
This comes from using the series representation of $\sinh{(\sin{(x)})}$ which is the following:
$$\sinh{(\sin{(x)})}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sin^{2k+1}(x)}{(2k+1)!}$$
and integrating both sides with respect to $x$ in the given range.